# Angular error when using mediaObserver in Angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-flex-layout

I ma getting the following error on my VS Code console after I have upgraded my Angular and Flex version from 12 to 14.

`Type 'Observable<void>' is missing the following properties from type 'Subscription': closed, _parentOrParents, _subscriptions, unsubscribe, and 2 more.ts(2740)`

```
 this.cols = this.mediaObserver.asObservable().pipe(
     map((change: MediaChange[]) => {
        this.deviceAlias = change[0].mqAlias;
     })
 )
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `this.cols` is declared as a `Subscription` but `this.mediaObserver.asObservable()` returns an observable.
either you need to add `.subscribe()` or you need to declare `this.cols` as an observable.

alos you are using `map()` incorrectly. `map()` needs to return something. If you don't need to return anything, use `tap()` instead